# Apply Transforms on object copies not working

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, objects, transforms

I have two objects which I want to make copies of them and apply transforms for these copies. I'm using the below script but it doesn't work and I don't know why?

```
obj1c=bpy.data.objects['Obj1']
obj2c=bpy.data.objects['Obj2']

obj1c = obj1c.copy()
obj2c = obj2c.copy()
obj1c.data = obj1c.data.copy()
obj2c.data = obj2c.data.copy()

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

obj1c.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj1c
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location = True, scale = True, rotation = True)
obj1c.select = False
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

obj2c.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj2c
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location = True, scale = True, rotation = True)
obj2c.select = False
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because the copies are not on the scene so you can't make them active. To do so the command is bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ob)

```
import bpy


obj1c=bpy.data.objects['Obj1']
obj2c=bpy.data.objects['Obj2']

obj1c = obj1c.copy()
obj2c = obj2c.copy()

obj1c.data = obj1c.data.copy()
obj2c.data = obj2c.data.copy()

bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj1c)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj2c)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

obj1c.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj1c
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location = True, scale = True, rotation = True)
obj1c.select = False
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

obj2c.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj2c
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location = True, scale = True, rotation = True)
obj2c.select = False
```